# mesh element id style

Tags: plotting, mesh, finite-element-method

I need help to make the elements id visible in the meshing code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

nx = 401;
ny = 51;
coordinates = 
 Flatten[Table[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]}, {r, 2., 3., 
    1/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 0., 3 Pi/3., (3 Pi/3.)/(nx - 1)}], 1]

incidents = 
  Flatten[Table[{j*nx + i, 
     j*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i + 1, (j - 1)*nx + i}, {i, 1, 
     nx - 1}, {j, 1, ny - 1}], 1];

MatrixForm[incidents];

mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[incidents]}];

mesh["Wireframe"]

mesh["ElementConnectivity"];

Show[mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]

Show[mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Blue]]]
```

when I run it I get the results as in the figure I need to make numbering smaller to be able to see it [image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get smaller font size with

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements",
  "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Directive[Red, "FontSize" -> 2]]
 ]
```

Comment: I tried that but give me nodes only with out numbering

Comment: Oh I did it and it is ok thank you

Comment: You're welcome! And good luck with reading those tiny numbers! :)